# Dihedral Groups of even order

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, dihedral-groups

I have this problem in which i have to proof that the Dihedral Group is of even order. I've seen some proofs which are somehow complicated, I proved it in a way that seems to me simple, but I'm new at proving and i want to know if my proof is correct.

The Dihedral group is the set of symbols $x^iy^j$ such that:
$$ x^i | i= 0, 1. y^j | j = 0, 1, ... , n-1 $$
$$ x^2 = e = y^n $$ 
$$ xy = y^{-1}x$$

First we prove that  $xy^j = y^{-j}x$ proceeding by induction. The case for 1 comes from the definition, let us now proof for k+1. 
$$ xy^{k+1} = (xy)y^k = y^{-1}xy^k = y^{-1}(xy^k) = y^{-1}(y^{-k}x) = y^{-(k+1)}x.$$ Which is what we wanted to prove.

Now, we prove that xy^j is of order 2.
$$ (xy^j)^2 = (xy^j)(xy^j) = (xy^j)(y^{-j}x) = x(y^jy^{-j})x = xx = e $$

Since $xy^j$ is of order 2 then by the Langrange Theorem, the order of the group must be a multiple of 2, which is what we wanted to proof.

Is my proof correct? Seems to me like it is. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You are given that $x^2 = e$ right off the bat.  Why not apply Lagrange immediately with that in mind?

Comment: Actually, this does not even prove that $xy^j$ is of order $2$ (in particular, it does not prove that $x$ is of order $2$). All this proves is that the order of $xy^j$ divides $2$, so it could equal $1$.

Comment: Kaj Hansen, I thought that x itself was not an element of the group, i thought only the product between and power of x and a power of y. Now I see is much more easier, thank you.

Comment: Lee Mosher. I proved for any j, and $xy^j = e$ is not true for every j, it comes from the definition and the fact that x it is its own inverse, and the fact that the inverse is unique.

Comment: The definition of the group as a set of symbols already allows you to count these symbols and figure out that their number is $2n$ without ever using any group theory. This does not mean all your hard work is in vain. What you do in essence is show that this set *indeed is* a group, so that the question makes sense. From an a priori standpoint the set would not be a group at all since any group built from that set contains also all sort of different symbols like $xy^2xy^4xy^{-1}x$ not in the original list. Your proof goes a long way to showing that all these can indeed be shortened to $x^iy^j$

Comment: ...which is valuable in itself

Comment: What is your definition of Dihedral group? If it's that it is the group of symmetries of the regular $n$-gon, then you still have to prove that this candidate group is *actually* (isomorphic to) the group of symmetries of the $n$-gon.